# Modal close on submit

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have this modal window that pops up when you open a page. I have problems closing it after submitting a form. It closes with a button and when you click outside it, but somehow I can't close it with a submit button.

My scripts

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');



var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];



span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

The button I want to close the modal with.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" > </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`elem.modal()`](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

1. Bootstrap need a jquery .so better do with jquery function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Methods</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <form>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"> </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```